# How many record to fetch google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Below my sample code

```
function getResponseData()
{
    var service = googleOAuth();
    var attachmentURL = https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainname/sitename?kind=attachment&start-index=1&max-results=500

 if(service.hasAccess())
 {
   var dataResponse;

   try 
   {
     dataResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(attachmentURL, {method: 'get',headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}});  
    } 
    catch(e)
    {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
}

function googleOAuth() 
{
  var service = OAuth2.createService('sites')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('')
    .setTokenUrl('').setClientId('').setClientSecret('').setProjectKey('').setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()).setScope('')
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()).setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
    return service;
 }

 function authCallback(request) 
 {
    var driveService = googleOAuth();
    var isAuthorized = driveService.handleCallback(request);
    if(isAuthorized)
    {
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
    }
    else
    {
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
    }
}
```

I have attached the google sites page 1500 documents and but get the lastest attachment document below 1000. how to get all documents. please help me.I have get the 996 document only retrieve. how to another document retrieve.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I created a google site of my own, uploaded 1500 files and wrote google apps script (similar to yours) to replicate this issue. As it turns out, I too am not able to retrieve files after the first 1000. This is happening even if I change the `start-index` and `max-results`. The only reason I can think of is that this is an undocumented limitation. There must be a limit of 1000 for the number of attachments. I might be wrong.

The limits for attachments to a Google Site are mentioned in this link - [Storage and file limits](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/96770?hl=en)

Comment: app script via document upload sites page in 500 files only. it now woking file upload, but not retrieve all documents. here is the reference link  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ContentFeedGET